# You'll have to rotate

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, word-search

Figure out how the two puzzles should connect. Use the following words:

- bkkz
- bwni
- hsklmjwk
- jlt
- jra
- luwujqrbui
- mktvmhk
- qfcdfchohwcb
- winnih
- wullin
- ywna

```
B E U C H I O N P D U S     D B U D W M R A F V E R
U I C O T T O N M L I K     Q W R E V E O O P U R S
R A A I C S M O P R S E     F S A V E Y T N T Y A E
F F R A U E U I O B A E     E R A C G B C S S P W S
H R E B N L R T S U I F     D I U D E K A I E A P Q
U D I S T B M A R D O F     F K N O T N R U X D E T
T S H P W A S T R O T E     U W O M A C T M E O S Z
S S A X K T C O D O R I     N S A B B A C P W O V B
E E T N D E E R M U G U     O M N H L D K O F F K J
E E R Y C G N P S T M H     T U A F E L E K P R H R
S R A A L E M O C O G C     T M U D S K R O D D O T
A V C R X V S R W O K N     O F S U O B R C I U E T
F K T O R R A C R R N S     C T O R R A C S H A S A
U U O W U N O E T Y E H     R E K O I B J N F E T N
T V R S D O D K G X F U     B E R S T P X C O I E I
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I started with juicifer's answer and noticed

> All words can be found in both grids.
>  [image]
>  
> I missed CARE in the second grid but Amoz pointed it out.

Then,

> you have to rotate and connect the grids
>  [image]
>  
>  and you get a tractor!

Comment: Okay, so the orange 'care' I found and rejected is the smokestack. Add that and this is solved!

Answer (score 7):

Going off the title,

> we can rotate the words based on the # of letters in each word.
>  For example, bkkz rot4 is food.
>  Here's the list.
>  bkkz > food
>  bwni > farm
>  hsklmjwk > pastures
>  jlt > mow
>  jra > mud
>  luwujqrbui > vegetables
>  mktvmhk > tractor
>  qfcdfchohwcb > croprotation
>  winnih > cotton
>  wullin > carrot
>  ywna > care

> We see each word appears in each grid once, with some exceptions:
>  A few (pastures 2x, crop rotation) appear in a circle.
>  Care in grid 2 is in a squiggly line (orange).
>  [image: step1]

> For "care" being squiggly, this is not in line with the theme, nor does it give a way to 'connect' the grids. Instead, let's find the second 'care' in a circle that spans both grids, matching a known mechanism (since a straight line one doesn't exist).
>  In line with the title, we'll have to rotate to do it!
>  [image: step 2]
>  Now the two puzzles are connected!
>  However, since there are two C's to choose from, I'm not sure this step is satisfactory, but don't see a good reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: I have edited my post, sorry for the typo. now you are able to find 'care' correctly.

Comment: It was fine, smoke is squiggly, I can't believe I didn't see the obvious picture; got too hung up on searching for that last word : )

Comment: Can't believe that you still found it, almost at the right place. Really like your creativity for joining the two :)

Answer (score 6):

Based on the title,

> let's rotate these words based on their length:
>
>  - bkkz -> rot 4 -> **food**
>  - bwni -> rot 4 -> **farm**
>  - hsklmjwk -> rot 8 -> **pastures**
>  - jlt -> rot 3 -> **mow**
>  - jra -> rot 3 -> **mud**
>  - luwujqrbui -> rot 10 -> **vegetables** (ew, rot-ten vegetables!)
>  - mktvmhk -> rot 7 -> **tractor**
>  - qfcdfchohwcb -> rot 12 -> **croprotation**
>  - winnih -> rot 6 -> **cotton**
>  - wullin -> rot 6 -> **carrot**
>  - ywna -> rot 4 -> **care**

Now, we can find some of these words in the word search:

> ... but not all of them:
>
>  [image: the word search, with 10 of the 11 words found]

It turns out that

> PASTURES is not in a straight line in either grid ...
>
>  but it is found in a circular pattern in both grids!
>
>  [image: the grids again, but with PASTURES highlighted]

Presumably,

> this is how the grids should align:
>
>  [image: the grids overlaid, with the circles matching up]